# How do to get single item detail page from listview page Using QML?

Tags: qt, qml

This listview Page Code is here

```cpp
import QtQuick 2.9
import QtQuick.Controls 2.2
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.3

Item {

    ListModel {
        id: mymodel
            ListElement {
                name: 'Jack'
                age: 30
                rank: 'Captain'
            }
            ListElement {
                name: 'Barbossa'
                age: 23
                rank: 'Sailor'
            }
            ListElement {
                name: 'Philip'
                age: 19
                rank: 'Sergent'
            }
        }
    ListView {
        id: list
        width: parent.width
        height: parent.height
        anchors.centerIn: parent
        spacing: 10
        model: mymodel
        delegate: Rectangle {
            // property variant myData: model
            width: parent.width
            height: 20
            color: 'Blue'
            Text {
                anchors.centerIn: parent
                color: 'white'
                text: 'Name: ' + name + ', Age: ' + age
                font.pointSize: 20
            }
            MouseArea {
                    anchors.fill: parent
                    onClicked: list.currentIndex = index
                }
            Button {
                    width: 50
                    height: parent.height
                    anchors.right: parent.right
                    text: ">"

                    onClicked: {
                    list.currentIndex = index
                    mystackview.push(third_page);
                    }
                }
        }
    }
}
```

Here is picture after running

[image]

Another code page is after clicking next arrow to get single item detail

```cpp
import QtQuick 2.9
import QtQuick.Controls 2.2
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.3

Item {    
    Rectangle {
         width: parent.width
            height: 20
            color: 'red'
            ListView {
                 model: model
            }
            Text {
                anchors.centerIn: parent
                color: 'white'
                text: 'Name: ' + ListModel.model.name 
                font.pointSize: 20
            }
    }
}
```

But this error shows

> Type Error: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined)

What is the solution for this?

Comment: What do you expect from this ```ListModel.model.name```  line of code?

Comment: Your question is unclear, explain yourself better

Comment: Hello Roya Ghasemzadeh I expect from to select any item or index for detail page like contact page. I use it separation page with stackview.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code `ListModel.model.name` does not make sense since the ListModel that is a component (class) does not have that property. In this case it is better to create a property that handles the currentIndex between the pages and the model is used directly.

**main.qml**

```
import QtQuick 2.9
import QtQuick.Controls 2.2

ApplicationWindow {
    id: window
    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 480
    title: qsTr("Stack")

    ListModel {
        id: mymodel
        ListElement {
            name: 'Jack'
            age: 30
            rank: 'Captain'
        }
        ListElement {
            name: 'Barbossa'
            age: 23
            rank: 'Sailor'
        }
        ListElement {
            name: 'Philip'
            age: 19
            rank: 'Sergent'
        }
    }

    QtObject{
        id: internals
        property int currentIndex: -1
    }

    StackView {
        id: stackView
        anchors.fill: parent
        initialItem: "TodoView.qml"
    }
}
```

**TodoView.qml**

```
import QtQuick 2.9
import QtQuick.Controls 2.2

Item {
    ListView {
        id: list
        model: mymodel
        anchors.fill: parent
        spacing: 10
        delegate: Rectangle {
            width: parent.width
            height: 20
            color: 'Blue'
            Text {
                anchors.centerIn: parent
                color: 'white'
                text: 'Name: ' + name + ', Age: ' + age
                font.pointSize: 20
            }
            MouseArea {
                anchors.fill: parent
                onClicked: list.currentIndex = index
            }
            Button {
                width: 50
                height: parent.height
                anchors.right: parent.right
                text: ">"
                onClicked: {
                    list.currentIndex = index
                    internals.currentIndex = index
                    stackView.push("DetailView.qml")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**DetailView.qml**

```
import QtQuick 2.9
import QtQuick.Controls 2.2
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.3

Item {
    Rectangle {
        width: parent.width
        height: 20
        color: 'red'
        Text {
            anchors.centerIn: parent
            color: 'white'
            text: 'Name: ' + mymodel.get(internals.currentIndex).name
            font.pointSize: 20
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much eyllanesc

Comment: eyllanesc i sent your email to get example code. Will you check it? please